# How to Inspect git traffic in Fiddler

Tags: git, networking, fiddler

Similar to the question on using [a proxy (like fiddler) to intercept requests made from Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8697344/1366033), is it possible to listen to communications made by git

Local git commands like `checkout` and `commit` don't make any external requests.
But remote commands like `push` and `pull` should make network requests

However, they don't show up in fiddler when monitoring "All Processes"

Answer (score 3):

Per Will Anderson's post on [Inspecting Git Traffic in Fiddler](https://willi.am/blog/2014/05/08/inspecting-git-traffic-in-fiddler/), you can route git traffic to fidler by setting the git config:

```bash
git config --global http.proxy 127.0.0.1:8888
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

Then when you're done, undo by calling `--unset` on the config properties:

```bash
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset http.sslVerify
```